# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar este código para que sea más pequeño? - python

Tags: python, optimización

```
continuar = True
while continuar:
  categoria = input("Introduce categoria:")
  if categoria != "cancelar":
    precio = int(input("Introduce el precio del producto:"))    
    if categoria == "productos lacteos":      
      total = precio - (precio * .1)
      print ("Descuento del 10%. Por pagar: ", total)       
    elif categoria == "productos horneados":
      total = precio - (precio * .3)
      print ("Descuento del 30%. Por pagar: ", total) 
    else:
      print ("No hay descuento. Por pagar: ", precio) 
  else:
    continuar = False
print("compra cerrada")
```

Se que funciona bien, pero la plataforma no me deja avanzar a la siguiente actividad hasta que no este "exactamente igual" a su resultado. Hay manera de hacerlo con menos lineas de código?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Cuál es el error que aparece en la plataforma? Dudo que la plataforma valide que el código sea exactamente igual, normalmente ponen casos de prueba y si falla alguno entonces te dice la razón.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de hacer el loop lo puedes cambiar por un `While True`

```
while True:
    categoria = input("Introduce categoria:")
    if categoria == "cancelar":
        break
    ...
    ...
print("compra cerrada")
```

Si puedes usar un diccionario:

```
d = {'productos lacteos': 10, 'productos horneados': 30}


    if categoria == "cancelar":
        break
    precio = int(input("Introduce el precio del producto:"))
    if categoria in d:
        total = precio * (100 - d[categoria]) / 100
        print(f"Descuento del {total}%. Por pagar: ")
        #  print("Descuento del {}%. Por pagar: {}".format(d[categoria], total))
    else:
        print("No hay descuento. Por pagar: ", precio)
print("compra cerrada")
```

Con un **operador ternario** puedes eliminar varias lineas.

```
    print( (f'Descuento del {d.get(categoria)}%. ' if categoria in d else "No hay descuento. ") + f'Por pagar {total}' )
```

El código completo:

```
d = { 'productos lacteos': 10, 'productos horneados': 30 }

while True:
    categoria = input("Introduce categoria:")
    if categoria == "cancelar":
        break
    precio = int(input("Introduce el precio del producto:"))
    total = precio * (100 - d.get(categoria, 0) ) / 100

    print( (f'Descuento del {d.get(categoria)}%. ' if categoria in d else "No hay descuento. ") + f'Por pagar {total}' )

print("compra cerrada")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Lo voy a intentar asi :D